# How to implement customized row-by-row accumulation calculation

Tags: python, pandas

The row-by-row cumulative calculation methods in pandas only include cummin, cummax, cumsum, and cumprod. If I want to implement other logic, how should I implement it (in addition to row-by-row looping).

For example, I want to implement the following logic, the next row increases by 1/2 of the previous row

```
df = pd.DataFrame({"A":[1,2,3]})
for i in range(1, len(df)):
    df.loc[i, "A"] = df.loc[i, "A"] + df.loc[i-1, "A"]*1/2
df
```

Is there a more efficient function that can implement this calculation logic?

Answer (score 2):

Absolutely, use the "shift" and "cumsum" functions, here's an implementation:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({"A": [1, 2, 3]})

# Calculate the cumulative sum of 1/2 times the previous row and add it to the original column
df['A'] = df['A'].add((df['A'].shift() * 1/2).cumsum().fillna(0))

print(df)
```

Comment: The results differ from the third row onwards.